# nohup stops the process as soon as I press enter

Tags: linux, process, nohup

I'm trying to run a script, say `script.py` that **does not take any input from the terminal** in the background using `nohup` by

```
nohup python3 script.py &
```

This command worked perfectly the last time I used it (and the script kept running for days!), but some error interrupted the process and it stopped. Eventually, `nohup.out` contained no error. (Is it supposed to?)

Now, I'm trying to run the script again, but am failing to do so. I use the same command, and then open the running processes using `top` but I get:

```
[2]-  Stopped                 nohup python3 script.py

[3]+  Stopped                 nohup python3 script.py
```

I am failing to understand why is this happening now. Any help is appreciated!

**P.S:** The script runs perfectly without `nohup`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup#Overcoming_hanging